# How to extract array element from array column?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm working with a dataset available here: https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/lehaknarnauli/spotify-datasets?select=artists.csv. What I want to do is to extract first element of each array in column `genres`. For example, if I got ['pop', 'rock'] I'd like to extract 'pop'. I tried different approaches but none of them works, I don't know why.

Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('artists.csv')

# approach 1
df['top_genre'] = df['genres'].str[0]
# Error: 'str' object has no attribute 'str'

# approach 2
df = df.assign(top_genre = lambda x: df['genres'].str[0])
# The result is single bracket '[' in each row. Seems like index=0 refers to first character of a string, not first array element.

# approach 3
df['top_genre'] = df['genres'].apply(lambda x: '[]' if not x else x[0])
# The result is single bracket '[' in each row. Seems like index=0 refers to first character of a string, not first array element.
```

Why these approaches doesn't work and how to make it work out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `genres` column seems to not actually be a list, but instead, a string that contains a list such as `"['a', 'b']"`. You will have to use `eval` on the string to convert each row into a list object again, but for safety reasons, its better to use `ast.literal_eval`

#### Using Converter during reading the dataset

One way is to apply a converter while loading the dataset itself using the `converters` parameter. The advantage of this method is that you can do multiple transformations and typecasting using a single dictionary, which can apply on a large number of similar files at once, if needed.

```
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.read_csv('/path_do_data/artists.csv', 
                 converters={'genres': literal_eval})
df['genres'].str[0]
```

```
0                        NaN
1                        NaN
2                        NaN
3                        NaN
4                        NaN
                 ...        
1104344                  NaN
1104345    deep acoustic pop
1104346                  NaN
1104347                  NaN
1104348                  NaN
```

---

#### Using apply method on a column

Another way to solve this is to just convert the string using `literal_eval`. This step needs multiple lines of code to overwrite existing columns but works as well, just a bit redundant in my opinion.

```
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.read_csv('/path_do_data/artists.csv')
df['genres'] = df['genres'].apply(literal_eval)
df['genres'].str[0]
```

```
0                        NaN
1                        NaN
2                        NaN
3                        NaN
4                        NaN
                 ...        
1104344                  NaN
1104345    deep acoustic pop
1104346                  NaN
1104347                  NaN
```

Comment: Glad to help, feel free to mark it if it was helpful!

Comment: One more thing - even if I use this solution I still can't extract first element easily. E.g. `deep acoustic pop` - element `deep` can't be retrieved using `df['genres'].str[0]`. I would have to use more complex function to do this. How can I convert `genres` column to list of arrays?

Comment: the "deep acoustic pop" is the first genre in the list of genres present in the data. for that row `['deep acoustic pop', 'mississippi indie']` so the code is working as expected. i double-checked. so you can just use `df['genres'].str[0]` to get first element / genre from the list of genres in each row

Comment: do try and let me know if any issues.

Comment: `df['genres'].str[0]` gives me `deep acoustic pop`. Now, I want to get first element only - `deep`. I tried with `df['genres'].apply(lambda x: x.split(' ')[0][0])` but got an error that it's not allowed to use split with lists. Code: `df['genres'].str.split(' ')[0][0]` gives error `invalid index to scalar variable`

Comment: You can simply chain the `str` methods as such `df['genres'].str[0].str.split().str[0]`. Avoid using apply as its very slow compared to the vectorized `str` methods. This will work on the rows that have some text, but may fail on nan values. So you may need to do the `df['genres'].str[0]` first, then fill nan values, and then try the `df['genres'].str.split().str[0]` again. I am afk right now, so give me some time to   share a solution.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it:

```
import json
df["top_genre"]=df["genres"].apply(lambda x: None if x == '[]' else json.loads(x)[0])
```